# using sleep method in gui, not working

Tags: java, thread-sleep

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent evt)  
{
  if( combo1==true && !evt.getActionCommand().equals("correct"))
  {
    combo2 = true;
    combo1 = false;
    combo3 = false;
    outText.setText("One more try!");
  }
  else if( combo2==true && !evt.getActionCommand().equals("correct"))
  {
    combo1 = false;
    combo2 = false;
    combo3 = true;

    **outText.setText("Wrong!!");**

      //sleep for 1 second
    try {
            Thread.currentThread();
          Thread.sleep(1000);
         } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
    System.exit(0);
    }

    System.exit(0);
  }
  else if( !evt.getActionCommand().equals("correct"))
  {
    combo1=true;
    combo2=false;
    combo3=false;
    outText.setText("Two more tries!");
  }
  else
    outText.setText("Correct");
}
```

This is a part of my code for getting the right answer, but the line where it's marked with ** is not working with the sleep method in there. The program sleeps for a sec and closes, but wouldn't print out "Wrong!!" before it goes into sleep. If someone could help me that'd be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what *is* it printing? Are you getting errors? Does `outText.setText("One more try!");` work at all?

Comment: It was just not printing "Wrong!!" all the other ones were working fine. But it's solved now, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're blocking the method from completing execution with `Thread.sleep()`. Use a javax.swing.Timer` instead.

```
outText.setText("Wrong!!");
new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}).start();

// get rid of Thread.sleep()
```

See more at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)